# I would like to resize my /tmp partition but gparted doesn't want to change anything, nowhere

Tags: linux, debian, filesystems, mount, fstab

I use my computer with `Debian 9` for `Java` `Spark` development.
`Spark` is a Big Data API and these kind of works use more temporary space than the 2G that by default the `Debian` installation sat.

```
marc@bouleau:/data$ df -h
Sys. de fichiers Taille Utilisé Dispo Uti% Monté sur
udev                15G       0   15G   0% /dev
tmpfs              3,0G    9,7M  3,0G   1% /run
/dev/sda1           23G    9,7G   12G  45% /
tmpfs               15G     29M   15G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs              5,0M    4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs               15G       0   15G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda5          9,2G    2,3G  6,4G  26% /var
/dev/sda7          1,9G    6,0M  1,7G   1% /tmp
/dev/sdb1          1,8T     85G  1,7T   5% /data
/dev/sda8          171G     77G   85G  48% /home
tmpfs              3,0G     16K  3,0G   1% /run/user/115
tmpfs              3,0G     64K  3,0G   1% /run/user/1000
```

But currently I can't resize it by using a `mount` command : the relying filesystem isn't large enough. It appears that I have to reduce one filesystem and extends another, or give `/tmp` another mount point.

I've installed `gparted`. But using it in my `GNOME` session, it doesn't offer me to resize anything : I mean : for `/dev/sdb1` for example where I have 1,8T the resize options show for constants :
`minimal size : 1,8T, maximal size : 1,8T`
and therefore I can't change anything.

What is happening that makes `gparted` unable to changes my filesystems sizes ?
What is the simpliest (and the safer way) to solve my problem ?

The output of `lsblk` is :

```
marc@bouleau:/data$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 238,5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0  23,3G  0 part /
├─sda5   8:5    0   9,3G  0 part /var
├─sda6   8:6    0    30G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda7   8:7    0   1,9G  0 part /tmp
└─sda8   8:8    0   174G  0 part /home
sdb      8:16   0   1,8T  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   0   1,8T  0 part /data
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux you cannot change partitions on a drive that is mounted. You will need to boot from a live usb [[1](https://www.debian.org/CD/live/)], and first make more space by making `/swap` smaller from the end point (it looks too big anyway unless you have more than 15 Gb of ram). Otherwise make `/home` smaller from the start. You can then expand `/tmp` into the empty space.

With that said, I'm not sure that expanding `/tmp` is the best solution to your problem. I'm not familiar with Java development or spark but maybe you can set a directory in `/home` to work as temporary space.

Comment: That's a clever alternative, thanks !